# Падает android приложение с ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

Хочу вывести на экран список из имен. Приложение собирается, но на эмуляторе сразу же падает.

```
package com.example.arraylist;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<String> list;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list.add("Dima");
        list.add("Anton");
        list.add("Stas");
        list.add("Pasha");

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.array_adapter, list);

        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Не могу понять в чем проблема, подскажите пожалуйста. (В android и java только-только начал разбираться).

Comment: Перед `list.add("Dima");` добавьте `list = new ArrayList<>();`.